# $lookup returning all data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, lookup

I'm in the following scenario: I have two collections, **medicos** and **clinicas**. Medicos is related to clinicas by its ObjectId. What I want is to get just the clinicas who have medicos inside it. So I have this code:

```
Clinicas.aggregate([
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    nome: "$nome"
                }

            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "medicos",
                localField: "medico.medicoId",
                foreignField: "_id._id",
                as: 'result'
            }
        },
```

But something is wrong: it returns all medicos in the *as: 'result'*. For example: I have 4 documents in the medicos collection, and two documents in clinicas collection. The first clinicas has 2 medicos and the second one has 1 but the *as: 'result'* array brings to me all medicos documents for the 2 clinicas collection, as you can see.

[image: this just have 1 medicos]  [this have 2 medicos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8nKR.png)

Model **medicos**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const MedicoSchema = new Schema({
  //cod_medico:{type:Integer},
  nome:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 80  
  },
},
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('medicos', MedicoSchema);
```

And in the database the collection name is also 'medicos'

Comment: Try to change `foreignField: "_id._id"` to `foreignField: "_id"`. Post please sample for `medicos`

Comment: if i set foreignField: "_id" it returns any data

Comment: Lookin at the results, the source document did not actually contain the localField, i.e. there is no `medico.medicoId` field in that result, likely because it was removed by the $group.  The documents in the target collection did not contain an `_id._id` field.  $lookup matches localField:missing with foreignField:missing, giving you all of the documents.

Comment: @Joe thanks. Its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the group, you are first changing the id and after this, joining the data using the new id. Try to change the order of the pipeline, or removing the group stage. Like this:

```
db.clinica.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "medicos",
            localField: "medico.medicoId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: 'result'
        }
    },
```

])

Comment: the $group was in the wrong place. Thanks to you everything is fine now ^^